# Using Haxe macros to instantiate a class with parameters

Tags: macros, haxe

I'm trying to make some dark magic with macros in Haxe, I have a class named `Entity` and I want to add a pool with the `static` and `private` modifiers:

`Pool.hx`:

```
package exp;

class Pool<T> {
    public function new(clazz:Class<T>) {
        
    }
}
```

`Entity.hx`:

```
package exp;

@:build(exp.PoolBuilder.build())
class Entity {
    public function new(){}
}
```

`PoolBuilder.hx`:

```
package exp;

import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.Type;

class PoolBuilder {
    static public macro function build() : Array<Field> {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        var clazz = Context.getLocalClass();

        var typePath = { name:"Pool", pack:["exp"], params: [TPType(TPath({name: "Entity", pack: ["exp"]}))] }
        var pool = macro new $typePath(/* clazz? */);
        fields.push({
            name: "_pool",
            access: [APrivate, AStatic],
            pos: Context.currentPos(),
            kind: FVar(macro: exp.Pool, pool)
        });

        return fields;
    }
}
```

I have a problem with the `typePath` params, and passing a `Class<T>` as an argument to the constructor. The compiler display this error:

> exp/Entity.hx:3: characters 1-7 : Invalid number of type parameters for exp.Pool
>
> exp/Entity.hx:4: lines 4-6 : Defined in this class

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building fields manually like that is somewhat tedious - I'd recommend to use [class reification](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-class.html) instead, where you can express the field as regular Haxe code:

```
macro class {
    static var _pool = new Pool(/* clazz */);
}
```

This bypasses the "Invalid number of type parameters" issue entirely - just let type inference do the trick and omit the type parameter in `new Pool()`.

The argument for the constructor call is of course variable, so we still need to use some [expression reification](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-expression.html). `exp.Entity` is a field expression, so we have to use `$p{}`. We can construct the type path needed for it by combining `clazz.pack` and `clazz.name`:

```
class PoolBuilder {
    static public macro function build():Array<Field> {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        var clazz = Context.getLocalClass().get();
        var path = clazz.pack.concat([clazz.name]); // ["exp", "Entity"]

        var extraFields = (macro class {
            static var _pool = new Pool($p{path});
        }).fields;
        return fields.concat(extraFields);
    }
}
```

This generates the following code (as can be seen in `exp/Entity.dump` with `-D dump=pretty`):

```
static var _pool:exp.Pool<exp.Entity> = new exp.Pool(exp.Entity);
```

Comment: This is really helpful, my life making macros will be easier now! Sometimes i think "i get it" but not really, it's hard to learn all about haxe macros. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer adding fields by `fields.push({...})` instead of using class reification, you can trigger type inference by using `null` as a type in `FVar(null, pool)`:

```
static public macro function build() : Array<Field> {
    var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
    var clazz = Context.getLocalClass().get();

    var path = clazz.pack.concat([clazz.name]); // ["exp", "Entity"]
    var pool = macro new exp.Pool($p{path});
    fields.push({
        name: "_pool",
        access: [APrivate, AStatic],
        pos: Context.currentPos(),
        kind: FVar(null, pool)
    });

    return fields;
}
```

This is using @gama11 trick for `path`. This generates the exact same code as @gama11 answer (and can be checked in the same way).

Comment: I didn't know how to do class reification, i think it's a better approach instead of building fields manually for people like me with a basic knowledge of macros, but i will remember your tips. Thanks!